# XML elements not displaying in HTML page?

Tags: html, css, xml, dom, xslt

I am having a bit of a problem. I have begun creating a HTML page, and have a seperate document for my XML and I need to display certain elements from the XML into the HTML Page. I have been on W3 School and used the following code and try to manipulate it into my HTML page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="loadxmldoc.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
  xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("books.xml");

  document.write(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>");
  document.write(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("author")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>");
  document.write(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("year")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

However all i get is what i made in HTML, and nothing with regards to the XML. I created another document with strictly the above code and all i get is a white page. I have tried Internet explorer and chrome for this. Link to the W3 school is:

http://www.w3schools.com/dom/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_parsertest

Any help please?

Comment: What does `loadxmldoc.js` look like? What does `books.xml` look like? What does your browser's JavaScript console report?

Comment: @Quentin - If he's using the W3S example then books.xml is here: http://www.w3schools.com/dom/books.xml .  I suspect the problem is somewhere in loadxmldoc.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tweaked your code a little and the following works.  I've taken it from the w3s tutorial I think you're using.  I think you can safely delete the IE5/6 specific code!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else // IE 5/6
  {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xhttp.open("GET","books.xml",false);
xhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xhttp.responseXML;
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
  document.write(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>");
  document.write(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("author")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>");
  document.write(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("year")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm assuming here that your books.xml file is the one here
http://www.w3schools.com/dom/books.xml

One caveat - it only works if you view it through a webserver - so you need to use a development server on your own PC or upload it somewhere, it won't work if you open it directly in a browser.

For what it's worth I recommend XSLT for handling XML
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xsl.asp

Comment: Thanks =) I have opted to XSLT and its definately made my life alot more easier. Thanks for the recommendation =)